# List of multiple widgets under app name?

Tags: android-widget

I've been searching for hours for answer to this: How do I make all my widgets appear under my app name when choosing a widget?  I've created a bunch of different AppWidgetProviders for each widget size, but they all just list separately in the top level of the widget list.  Example:

```
<receiver 
        android:name=".WidgetProvider1x1"
        android:label="@string/widget_1x1" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info_1x1" />
    </receiver>
    <receiver 
        android:name=".WidgetProvider1x2"
        android:label="@string/widget_1x2" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info_1x2" />
    </receiver>
    <receiver 
        android:name=".WidgetProvider1x3"
        android:label="@string/widget_1x3" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/ widget_info_1x3" />
    </receiver>
```

This is just directly under  in my manifest - does it need a different hierarchy or a different naming scheme?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. There is a replacement AppWidgetPicker for Rooted phones that does this automatically - [AppWidgetPicker](http://www.robotbriefs.com/news/2010/9/16/appwidgetpicker-condenses-your-widget-list-root-froyo-only.html)

You best bet is to define just one widget and setup your widget configuration activity to show a list of different Widget sizes / configurations, and based on user selection setup the appropriate view on the Widget.